# Mock location not being set

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I've been trying to use mock locations to test my app, but the mock location doesn't appear to be used.

I've enabled mock mode on the LocationClient, included the permissions 'android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION' and set a mock location using the following code:

```
            if(!lonTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !latTxt.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                Location mockLoc = new Location("MOCK");
                mockLoc.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lonTxt.getText().toString()));
                mockLoc.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latTxt.getText().toString()));
                mockLoc.setAccuracy(5.0f);
                mockLoc.setAltitude(0);
                mockLoc.setBearing(0);
                mockLoc.setSpeed(0);
                mockLoc.setTime(new Date().getTime());

                mLocationClient.setMockLocation(mockLoc);

                lonTxt.getText().clear();
                latTxt.getText().clear();
            }
```

Yet onLocationChanged() never gets called. I've set a location request for every second, high accuracy. Also, getLastLocation() returns null every time. Mock locations is enabled in developer options too. Am I missing something obvious? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm targeting android 4.4.2, running on Nexus 5. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having this problem.